# Amount of simultaneous HTTP requests are limited to four

Tags: scala, akka

I am learning Scala and Akka by attempting to create a command-line tool which will send HTTP requests to every URL in a text file.

So far I have made a code which creates 8 actors and send a link to each of them, while testing this I found that there's only four requests being sent at a time. The reason why I found this is that the URL i'm using for testing this is the same and consists of PHP code that sleeps for three seconds and displays a message.

The output is

```
HttpResponse(200 OK,List(Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 15:40:00 GMT, Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)),HttpEntity.Strict(text/html; charset=UTF-8,2 bytes total),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
HttpResponse(200 OK,List(Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 15:40:00 GMT, Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)),HttpEntity.Strict(text/html; charset=UTF-8,2 bytes total),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
HttpResponse(200 OK,List(Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 15:40:00 GMT, Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)),HttpEntity.Strict(text/html; charset=UTF-8,2 bytes total),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
HttpResponse(200 OK,List(Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 15:40:00 GMT, Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)),HttpEntity.Strict(text/html; charset=UTF-8,2 bytes total),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
HttpResponse(200 OK,List(Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 15:40:03 GMT, Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)),HttpEntity.Strict(text/html; charset=UTF-8,2 bytes total),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
HttpResponse(200 OK,List(Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 15:40:03 GMT, Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)),HttpEntity.Strict(text/html; charset=UTF-8,2 bytes total),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
HttpResponse(200 OK,List(Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 15:40:03 GMT, Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)),HttpEntity.Strict(text/html; charset=UTF-8,2 bytes total),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
HttpResponse(200 OK,List(Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 15:40:03 GMT, Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)),HttpEntity.Strict(text/html; charset=UTF-8,2 bytes total),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
```

I'm quite stumped as to why this is happening, I wondered if it had anything to do with a configuration file but I created one (and made sure it's loaded) and the maximum thread limit should be 32.

application.conf

```
akka {
  actor{
    default-dispatcher {
      type = Dispatcher
      executor = "thread-pool-executor"
      throughput = 1000    
      fork-join-executor {
        parallelism-min = 32
        parallelism-factor = 0.5
        parallelism-max = 64
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have added the code below in hope that anyone has the answers.

````
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{ Failure, Success }
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import com.typesafe.config._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

case class Request(url: String)

class HTTPActor extends Actor {
  import context.dispatcher
  
  def receive = {
    case Request(url) =>
      var request = Http(context.system).singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = url)) transformWith {
        case Success(resp) =>
          println(resp)
          Future.successful(Right(()))
        case Failure(e) =>
          Future.successful(Left(e))
      }
      Await.result(request, 10 seconds)
  }
}

object Example1 extends App {
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("HTTPRequest")
  import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
 
  val value = ConfigFactory.load()

  var actors = ArrayBuffer[akka.actor.ActorRef]()

  // Start the actors
  for(a <- 1 to 8) {
    actors += actorSystem.actorOf(Props[HTTPActor], name = s"HTTPRequestActor${a}") 
  }

  for(key <- 0 to 7) {
      actors(key) ! Request("http://127.0.0.1/test.php")
  }
}```
````

Comment: how many cpu cores do you have ?

Answer (score 1):

Good catch and this is expected. 4 is the default host-connection-pool.max-connections. Feel free to read [doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/pool-overflow.html#pool-overflow-and-the-max-open-requests-setting) to understand what the config does and refer to [reference.conf](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html) for the default config.

If you want to override the settings, you should probably override `akka-http.host-connection-pool.max-connections` to a different value in your application.conf or some sort.

Comment: @Aces can you accept the answer if it helps? Thanks